# C/C++ library with map()/mapto() function?

Tags: c++, c, math

What I'm searching for is a function which allows mapping a certain numeric value of a certain numeric range onto another. I did find a way to create this function manually, which has the basic calculation `output = output_start + ((output_end - output_start) / (input_end - input_start)) * (input - input_start)`, however I find it rather bothersome to always create it myself, search through my old projects to find it or to create a header file only for this function.

I'd imagine it's such a basic function that it should be somewhere in the C/C++ Standard libraries or at least in one of the mainstream 3rd party libraries, however I couldn't find it.

Comment: It should live in your personal library. That's where you put things you've written that you expect will be useful to you in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a linear transformation function, that for every number in the range `[input_start, input_end]` computes a number in the range `[output_start, output_end]` using a proportionality factor (i.e. `(output_end - output_start) / (input_end - input_start)` in order to cover the full range).

Unfortunately, this simple function doesn't exist in the standard library (e.g. neither in [`cmath`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cmath) nor [`numeric`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/numeric)).  Anyway, when using such a transformation, most frequently you'd like to compute the proportionality factor only once.

So the easiest way would be to create your own function for this.  In C++ you could create a class, which computes the factor at construction.